# Logback ClassCircularityError

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logback, slf4j

I changed from Windows to Ubuntu 17.04 and now I get an Error when I start the webapp on a Tomcat 8.0.36 via Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).

```
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/FilterReply
```

The project is build via M2E has AspectJ in it.

Uses following SLF4J Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

It work's under Windows Eclipse with almost same settings and installation.
Also it works when I `mvn clean package` (default ubuntu maven installation not eclipse one) and deployed it manually to the default Tomcat installation of Ubuntu.
I already changed my eclipse version to Oxygen and got the same problem. 
I tried to change the versions of the dependencies too - same result.

I have debuged the code to a "ServletContextListener" that tries to get a JDNI object:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator;
import ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter;

// ....

@Override
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
    new LogRecord(Level.FINEST, "Ensure class is loaded!");

    // Prepare logging context
    final LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    context.reset();

    // setup JUL to SLF4J log bridging
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
    final LevelChangePropagator levelChangePropagator = new LevelChangePropagator();
    levelChangePropagator.setResetJUL(true);
    levelChangePropagator.setContext(context);
    levelChangePropagator.start();
    context.addListener(levelChangePropagator);

    // Load context values
    String contextPath = sce.getServletContext().getContextPath().replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z-_]", "");
    if(contextPath.length() == 0){
        contextPath = "ROOT";
    }
    context.putProperty("appName", contextPath);
    final Boolean isProductiveVal = (Boolean) getJNDI(IS_PRODUCTIVE_JNDI);

// .....

private static Object getJNDI(final String jndiPath) {
    try {
        final Context initialContext = new InitialContext(); // << This line crashes
        return initialContext.lookup(jndiPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I have no clue what I could try to fix it. **And also im not fully understand the problem.** Tomcat tries to load a Class that reference it self?!

Does some one have a clue what I could check?

Full stack of Tomcat start.

```
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyProject' did not find a matching property.
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server number:         8.0.36.0
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Linux
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Version:            4.10.0-33-generic
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Architecture:          amd64
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.17.04.3-b11
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/kani/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat8
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:37177
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Drebel.base=/home/kani/.jrebel
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Drebel.env.ide.plugin.version=7.0.14
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Drebel.env.ide.version=4.6.3
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Drebel.env.ide.product=Eclipse
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Drebel.env.ide=eclipse
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Drebel.notification.url=http://localhost:17434
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Drebel.workspace.path=/home/kani/eclipse-workspace
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Drebel.properties=/home/kani/.jrebel/jrebel.properties
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -agentpath:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_7.0.14.RELEASE/jrebel/lib/libjrebel64.so
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/kani/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat8
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/kani/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat8/endorsed
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 802 ms
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
2017-09-06 17:05:37 JRebel: Directory '/home/kani/eclipse-workspace/MyProject/target/classes' will be monitored for changes.
2017-09-06 17:05:37 JRebel: Directory '/home/kani/eclipse-workspace/MyProject/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources' will be monitored for changes.
2017-09-06 17:05:37 JRebel: Directory '/home/kani/eclipse-workspace/MyProject/src/main/webapp' will be monitored for changes.
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:41 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 06, 2017 5:05:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/FilterReply
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:267)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:373)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:765)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:931)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:180)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.debug(DirectJDKLog.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: ClassCircularityError: Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine detects a circularity in the superclass hierarchy of a class being loaded.

Comment: Does the problem reproduce if you turn JRebel off?

Comment: Nope does not work eigther :(

Answer (score 0):

I changed to the Tomcat8 installation that I used in windows.
And it finally worked (I didn't know what the previous Head of did there).

The only difference I can see instantly is that it used Log4j also on Tomcat side. Maybe thats the difference. Sorry if someone else also have this problem and no solution.